# How to connect to Dataproc jupyternotebook in VPC-SC

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Without VPC-SC, I can connect to Jupyter lab on dataproc. However when the VPC-SC is turned on, then the web component is disabled. I am aware of the VPC-SC limitation, however, what is the work around solution?

Answer (score 1):

VPC-SC is designed to not permit data transfer across the security perimeter and this is essentially what any workaround would be.

VPC-SC is not currently supported but we are working on providing first-class support.

Comment: Thanks @tix, However, we just try to access the dataproc's jupyterlab for ML modeling with the data instead of transferring out the data. As such, can we access it by any other mean, like a VPC-SC vm connect to dataproc jupyterlab?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to [use an SSH tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces) to connect to the UI.

Since you mentioned accessing the UI without VPC-SC, I assume that you installed the Jupyter component and checked the "enable component gateway" button when you created your cluster.

If that is the case, then the port you want to connect to on the master node is 8443 and the URL path you want to use is "/jupyter/lab/".

So, for example, if you use the "GCLOUD COMMAND" options on the page I linked to, then the URL you would use after setting it up would be `http://<your-cluster-name>-m:8443/jupyter/lab`

Comment: Actually SSH and GCLOUD CMD are blocked in VPC-SC env, @_@

Comment: @Q4living you are right that VPC-SC complicates SSH connections. There has to be a route between your computer and the Dataproc cluster, and that may or may not be possible depending on your specific networking setup. If your network administrator can allow SSH connections from your computer to the cluster, then an SSH tunnel is the way to go. If they cannot, then you won't be able to connect to the notebook UI until the component gateway supports VPC-SC.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply ..... yes sadly SSH is not allowed at the moment, lets wait and see then